# Remove extra whitespace in UItableView

Tags: swift, uitableview

I've added a `tableView` in my `ViewController` and then a UItableView Cell.

I am getting this white space between my buttons and tableView.

How to fix?

[image: extra space]

Comment: Please, add your code to help you to fix this issue

Comment: for creating this i just used `Storyboard` :| no codes

Comment: what is the y position for your tableview?

Comment: Looks like the position or insets of `UITableView` are not set correctly to resemble your requirements... Check them in attributes inspector 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Select the view controller and on the utilities panel (the panel on right)
- Attributes inspector > View Controller > Layout
- Uncheck **Adjust Scroll View Insets**